# Conditional Summing in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 3 column dataframe named `df`:

```
Currency Product  Balance         
USD      A        10       
GBP      B        20       
USD      A        15       
GBP      A        5        
USD      B        30       
USD      A        20       
USD      B        5
```

And want to calculate the weight of each unique combination of product and currency.

The following code gives me the total for each combination:

```
df.groupby(['Currency','Product'])['Balance'].sum().
```

I wish to add a 4th column where I take the Balance number and divide it by looking up this aggregated value in the groupby table for that combination:

```
Currency Product  Balance  Weight       
USD      A        10       28.57%
GBP      B        20       100.00%
USD      A        15       42.86%
GBP      A        5        100.00%
USD      B        30       85.71%
USD      A        20       57.14%
USD      B        5        14.29%
```

Pseudo-code would be:

```
df['Weight'] = df['Balance'] / look up value in the groupby table above
```

The numerator in the weight is balance and the denominator is the total for the same product in that currency, so 3 products and 4 currencies would give us 12 totals.

Please help.

Comment: Please detail. Give input and expected output. And what you have tried so far.

Comment: check out `gb.Balance.transform(np.sum)`. it should return a like-indexed `Series` so you can just do `df['total'] = gb.Balance.transform(np.sum)` and then do normal operations after that (`df.Balance / df.total`)

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the balance by the [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) of the `groupby` (which keeps the same dimension as the original dataframe):

```
df['Weight'] = df.Balance / df.groupby(['Currency', 'Product']).Balance.transform(sum)

>>> df
  Currency Product  Balance    Weight
0      USD       A       10  0.222222
1      GBP       B       20  1.000000
2      USD       A       15  0.333333
3      GBP       A        5  1.000000
4      USD       B       30  0.857143
5      USD       A       20  0.444444
6      USD       B        5  0.142857
```

To better understand what is happening:

```
df['Sum'] = df.groupby(['Currency', 'Product']).Balance.transform(sum)

>>> df
  Currency Product  Balance    Weight  Sum
0      USD       A       10  0.222222   45
1      GBP       B       20  1.000000   20
2      USD       A       15  0.333333   45
3      GBP       A        5  1.000000    5
4      USD       B       30  0.857143   35
5      USD       A       20  0.444444   45
6      USD       B        5  0.142857   35

>>> df.groupby(['Currency', 'Product']).Balance.sum()
Currency  Product
GBP       A           5
          B          20
USD       A          45
          B          35
Name: Balance, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Many thanks! This is great - am getting to grips with split-apply-combine and this has helped my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could use apply:

```
agg = df.groupby(['Currency', 'Product']).sum()
df['weight'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Balance']/agg.loc[row['Currency']].loc[row['Product']], axis=1)
```